# Ajax / JQuery - Displaying flash message on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a fully working flash system in PHP and am using it to send the user a success message once I create an entry in the DB.

On one of my forms I have a select field which I want the user to be able to seamlessly add entries too it without directing them away from a semi-completed form. The code I'm using is working well. The user clicks on 'add a category' (in the select label) it opens a modal, the user creates a new category, it updates the DB and the select field and closes the modal using AJAX. All working.

What I need to do is use or adapt my flash system to give the user a message to say all good your entry was added. I am very new to AJAX and on a steep learning curve!

This is my AJAX / JQUERY code: (I followed a tutorial to get here. The idea is to make this usable across the site when I need to add entries to a select, by adding 'ajax' to the form class.)

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value) {
      var that = $(this),
          name = that.attr('name'),
          value = that.val();
      data[name] = value;
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {
        $('#select').load(document.URL +  ' #select');
        $('#addCategoryModal').modal('hide');
        $('#siteMessage').toast('show');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

And this is the PHP setting the DB record (working) and how I normally trigger a flash message on page reload (messages also work):

```
      //create record in db
      $newCategory = $this->blogModel->createCategory($formFields);
      if ($newCategory) {
        flash('siteMessage', 'Blog category added successfully');
      } else {
        flash('siteMessage', 'Something went wrong', 'bg-danger');
      }
```

And this is the flash code:

```
  function flash($name = '', $message = '', $class = 'bg-success') {
    if (!empty($name)) {
      if (!empty($message) && empty($_SESSION[$name])) {
        if (!empty($_SESSION[$name])) {
          unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }

        if (!empty($_SESSION[$name.'_class'])) {
          unset($_SESSION[$name.'_class']);
        }

        $_SESSION[$name] = $message;
        $_SESSION[$name.'_class'] = $class;
      } elseif (empty($message) && !empty($_SESSION[$name])) {
        $class = !empty($_SESSION[$name.'_class']) ? $_SESSION[$name.'_class'] : '';
        echo '
        <div id="siteMessage" class="toast shadow" data-delay="8000" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" style="position: absolute; top: 19px; right: 45%; z-index:10">
          <div class="toast-header '.$class.'">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2 pt-1 text-white"></i>
            <strong class="mr-auto text-white">Site Message</strong>
            <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
              <span class="text-white" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="toast-body">
            '.$_SESSION[$name].'
          </div>
        </div>
        ';
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        unset($_SESSION[$name.'_class']);
      }
    }
  }
```

My PHP processing page, creates the entry in the DB and I set the flash message as normal. I think I don't understand the interaction with how AJAX gets the returned success and setting a flash message.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This should probably not use a “flash message” mechanism to begin with. That was invented so that messages could be “collected” on the server side from different sources, so that they can all together be output on the next new page the user navigates to. The user doesn’t navigate anywhere else here, with the AJAX request - so this should not be technically necessary to begin with. (Rather on the contrary, with potentially several AJAX requests running at the same time, it could even easily become problematic.)

Comment: That makes sense. I shall search making the same formated toast via bootstrap :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe who pointed out the inherent problems with using a flash message mechanism I've added the following div at the bottom of the page and am now calling that direct with toast.show to give the message to the user.

I am not sure if that is the most affective way to do this but it works.

```
<div id="categoryMessage" class="toast shadow" data-delay="8000" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" style="position: absolute; top: 19px; right: 45%; z-index:10">
  <div class="toast-header bg-success">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2 pt-1 text-white"></i>
    <strong class="mr-auto text-white">Site Message</strong>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span class="text-white" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    The category was added successfully
  </div>
</div>
```